# How do I get the UDID of the iPod/iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have seen programs that do this, like the very useful 'BetaHelper' application.

How do I get the Unique Device Identifier of the iPod of iPhone that my application is running on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]

Comment: Some people have no sense of voting.